# Organizing actions into controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Alright... I need to list all uploads, downloads and requests made. But also I need to list all uploads, downloads and requests specific for a user. I'm not sure about where to place those actions in order to make it logical. The actions are returning their data as json.

- A upload is added when the user invokes `POST: Index(file)` in the `UploadsController`.
- A download is added when the user invokes `GET: Files(fileName)` in  the `UploadsController`.
- A request is added when the user invokes any `ActionResult` that is marked with a `LogAttribute`.

What my Controllers looks like:

UsersController

- GET: List
- GET: Create
- POST: Create(viewModel)
- POST: Delete(userID)
- GET: SignIn
- POST: SignIn(username, pwd)
- POST: SignOut

UploadsController

- GET: Index
- POST: Index(file)
- GET: Files(fileName)

---

Approach 1:

Create 2 new Controllers, `DownloadsController` and `RequestsController`. In both these controllers, and the `UploadsController` create the following Actions:

- GET: ListAll
- GET: ListFor(userID)

Approach 2:

Create a new controller, `StatsController` that has the following Actions:

- GET: ListAllUploads
- GET: ListUploadsFor(userID)
- GET: ListAllDownloads
- GET: ListUploadsFor(userID)
- GET: ListAllRequests
- GET: ListRequestsFor(userID)

As mentioned earlier, I'm not sure which (if any) of those 2 approaches makes sense. Could someone shed some light over, which would be "best"?

Answer (score 0):

Controllers should group functionally related Action methods - at least, such is my take. Would you have a several thousand line class that had unrelated methods in it that all did unique things? If not, don't think that a Controller is any different; it is a class with methods after all. I'd probably opt for either approach - both look good to me. It depends on what you prefer. I might even go MORE granular and have an UploadsController as well as the DownloadsController and RequestsController. These controller names will help isolate your views into unique folders, which is more human-friendly to other developers as well.

Comment: I agree here, controllers typically should work on the same objects in a logical manner. My only take would be to make the userId optional Parameter `RequestController.GetAll(int? userId)` and `UploadsController.GetAll(int? userId)` since the methods are after the same base objects, just with a different query... aka same url different querystring

Comment: @stuisme, Not quite. An example would be getting all _Requests_, when mapping them to a ViewModel, I'll have to get the _Username_ for the _UserID_ they have. - But getting _Requests_ for a specific _User_, I already know the _Username_ of the _User_, and therefore don't have to make an extra database call, in order to get the _Username_. - In short: The mapping logic differs, whether it's all _Requests_ or just for a specific _User_.. and that's how it works for _Uploads_ / _Downloads_ as well.